# section containing text overlaps a section containing an unordered list

Tags: html, css

Brand new html/css user here! I'm sure there's an easy and elegant way to solve this issue, but I haven't been able to find it.

I currently have four sections in my code, and the latter three seem to fall exactly how I would expect in relation to one another, one after the other, but the second one overlaps on top of the first one. I have gotten around this by adding an id to the second section that gives it some padding, but as you will notice, it is padding from the top of the page, not from the section above it. If I take that padding away, "About Me" overlaps on top of the background of the first section which contains the links.

```css
#firstlink {
  padding: 15px 50px 0px 0px
}
#linkbar {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 15%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
}
li {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 15px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
#aboutme {
  padding: 75px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="linkbar">
  <ul>
    <li id="firstlink">link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="aboutme">
  <h1>About Me</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Contact Me</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you for the very quick response. I tried removing the absolute from #linkbar, but if i take away the padding from #aboutme it still overlaps with top section, and also if i take away the absolute from #linkbar, the background color disappears

Comment: that doesn't seem to solve the problem of the overlap, as if i remove the float:right, and then remove the padding from #aboutme the overlap still occurs, and in addition it moves my links away from the position where I want them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on this fiddle, i think it is what you want - https://jsfiddle.net/swarn_singh/tv25eq3g/

```
#firstlink {
  padding: 15px 50px 0px 0px
}
#linkbar {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 15%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
}
li {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 15px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#firstlink {
  padding: 15px 50px 0px 0px
}
#linkbar {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;
      height: 15%;
      display: inline-block;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 15px 10px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#aboutme {
  padding: 75px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="linkbar">
  <ul>
    <li id="firstlink">link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="aboutme">
  <h1>About Me</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Contact Me</h1>
</section>
```